# Create custom profile for audio / configuration

Tags: 2.2-froyo, settings, profiles

I've just bought a Samsung Galaxy I5510 with Android 2.2. I haven't seen anywhere (so I assume it is not possible) some profile management. i.e. "Reunion" (Notifications maybe without any alert and calls and messages vibrate), or "Sleeping" (Notifications and messages without any alert and calls with sound and vibration), and so on.

I've a few default profile: sound (in)active, plane mode and driving mode (the one which "speaks to you"). But I'd really like to can create my custom profiles as described above.

In the title I put " / configuration" because it would be awesome that the profile also let me to set up each app. I.e. different configuration on the same application based on which is the active profile.

So here are my questions:

1. Is that functionality already in my phone and I am missing something?
2. If not, is there any app with this functionality? (If it is free, better, if it is not free I'd like to hear about it anyway).
3. If not, is this possible to be done by an app? (Because I may be interested in developing such app if it doesn't exists). Any advice? (I'd never developed anything for android).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd been using Tasker, but it was really difficult and worked to maintaining the profiles. I found PhoneWeaver. Much simpler!

Answer (score 5):

Try Tasker!
It does this and much much more :)

Developer website:
http://tasker.dinglisch.net/

Android market:
https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm

If the learning curve is a little steep for you I'd suggest "Setting Profile" even if less powerful than tasker.
Also "Locale" could be of help.
I think you need to combine more apps to achieve your result or just use Tasker as I've suggested :)

Comment: Does this Tasker app has any free version? Does it needs the phone to be root? Also in its features it says that phone settings can be change by app, time or location. It is also possible to do it manually between predefined values, right? What about settings of each app? Is that possible?

Comment: Hello Diego! You can find all the answers here: http://tasker.dinglisch.net/ anyway: no need of root and all you get is a trial to value if the software is worth your money. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Tasker that I have used is [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage), which unlike Tasker is free. With AutomateIt (and similarly with Tasker) is to define triggers that will causes actions to happen, for example, you might want to set the Media Volume to 80 when you plug the earphone and then mute it when you unplug, or you might want to setup different screen brightness for different time of the day (useful if your phone doesn't have a light sensor), or you might want to set different Notification Volumes when the phone is connected to the Office Wifi than to your Home Wifi.

You can freely mix and match these triggers and events and have very complex configuration; or you can simply use it to turn on and off your volumes.

Comment: I haven't seen anyway to create an icon to launch a task, so how would I manually launch a task? Is entering the app the only way?

Comment: @Diego: Yyou can long press on a rule to show a menu one of which is for manually executing the associated action, but I don't think it's possible to start an action through desktop icon (though I think it's a worthy feature request)